# Handling push notification while application is on background

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, push

I am trying to fire a procedure or service when receiving a push notification, however I want to do this while the application is running in the background.

I have already tested that it works with the application on foreground, but also need it to do some work when in background if receiving the notification.

I have asked around and have been told that cannot be done, however i would like to ask here to confirm it, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, You can achieve this. You need to send push message with data payload and without notification payload.
[Check the doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive)

Comment: Note: this works perfectly on android. However on ios, just a data tag inside the push will not get delivered until either the application is running or is backgrounded. So if you are looking at multi platform pushes... Keep this in mind :)

Answer (score 0):

> When your app is in the background, Android directs notification messages to the system tray

On Android, when your app is on foreground and a push notification is sent from your server side with both 'notification' and 'data' keys, OnMessageReceived method in your FireBaseMessagingService will be called. In this same case, when your app is in background, OnMessageReceive will not be called.

However, when a push notification is sent from your server side with only the 'data' key, OnMessageReceive will be called even if your app is running in background or foreground BUT you will have to handle the insertion of the notification in the user's notification tray yourself